# detectar espacios en blanco y sacar error

Tags: c

estoy intentando cuando le pase por teclado un numero y un array de caracteres a un programa, me detecte si esta en el orden correcto y si el array tiene espacios. De momento conseguí el tema del orden, pero no soy capaz de que me detecte los espacios en blanco para poder sacar el error.

```
 int main(){
char text[20];
int n;
printf("dame una cadena con formato ID Nombre");
scanf("%d %99[0-9a-zA-Z ]s",&n,text);
if(n>0)
    
    printf("ID: %d\nNombre: %s\n",n,text);
if(text[1]==0){
    printf("Formato Incorrecto\n");
}
}
```

Comment: Eres compañero de clase de [Fran](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488859/problema-de-clase-programamcion-en-c)? Parece que estan con el mismo problema. De todos modos, cito lo que le comente a el, puede que te sirva:

Comment: "*Puedes leerla usando fgets, y luego validar el formato. Para validarlo puedes usar sscanf, haciendo algo tipo: if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %s %n", &id, name, &characters_read) != 3 && characters_read != strlen(buffer)) {printf("Formato incorrecto: %s", buffer);}*"

Comment: `%99[0-9a-zA-Z ]s`, entre los caracteres que aceptas hay espacios, solo quitalos entre los caracteres que aceptas. Ademas, dices que el maximo de caracteres para el `scanf` es `99`, pero `text` solo tiene un tamaño de `20`. Esa es una formula para el desastre.